# The distribution of $\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i} \cos(i\theta)$

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, summation, normal-distribution

if $X=\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i}$ is a random variable that follows normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma)$.

Is it possible to find the distribution of the variable $Y$:
 $$Y=\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i} \cos(i\theta)$$

Because we can not split the sum I can not see if there is another trick.

Thank you.

Comment: Two questions. Do you know whether each $a_i$ is independent or not? And, in the expression with $\cos$ is $i = \sqrt{-1}$ or is it the integer $i$ overwhich you are summing?

Comment: in my case $a_{i}=1$ and I know that that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} 1$ follows a normal distribution (this result is related to geometric graphs where the sum of all ones is the number of edges). The $i$ is the integer over which I am summing.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by $a_i = 1$, since this is a random variable.

Comment: $a_{i}$ is not a random variable but the sum $\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i}$ is a random variable.

Comment: I think there may be some confusion with terminology here; a sum of numbers can only be a random variable, if either its constituent variables are also random (i.e. the $a_i$), or the number $n$ over which we sum is a random variable. Which of these two cases are you considering?

Comment: If it is the case that you are wanting to sum a random number of $1$s, i.e. in your interpretation this might be the total number of edges in a random graph, then it is not possible for this to follow a normal distribution. For instance, the probablity of having a negative (or fractional) answer to the number of edges is always $0$, however this is non-zero for a normal distribution.

Answer (score 0):

In general I do not think you will be able to get a simple closed formula for the distribution.

However, under the assumption that each of the terms $a_i$ are independent, then we can get an expression for the Moment Generating Function. This is then sufficient for deriving the mean, variance etc. of the distribution.

We first note the following fact: If $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables and $X + Y$ is normally distributed, then both $X$ and $Y$ are normally distributed (according to [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/28787/decomposing-the-normal-distribution/28808#28808) post, a proof is in Feller's book *An Introduction to Probability Theory and Its Applications*).

As such, we can assume that each of the $a_i \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_i, \sigma^2_i)$, where

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \mu_i = \mu, \qquad \sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i^2 = \sigma^2.$$

Then we can compute the moment generating function (making use of the independence of the $a_i$) to be

\begin{align*}
\varphi(s) \,\colon & = \mathbf{E}\left[ \exp\left( s \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \cos(i \theta) \right) \right] \\
& = \prod_{i=1}^n \mathbf{E}\left[ \exp\left(  a_i \cos(i \theta) \right) \right] \\
& = \prod_{i=1}^n \exp \left( s \mu_i \cos(i \theta)+ \frac{s^2}{2} \sigma_i^2 \cos^2(i \theta)\right) \\
& = \exp \left( s \sum_{i=1}^n \mu_i \cos(i \theta) + \frac{s^2}{2} \sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i^2 \cos^2(i \theta) \right).
\end{align*}